# How to print a hash of hashes with vector values into a tab delimited file of columns?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

Perl beginner here. I have built a hash oh hashes where the 'final' value is an array of strings.
It looks like this:

```
my %sampleHash = ()

$sampleHash{$sample1} = {
    R1Tests  => \@sample1Results_1,
    R2Tests  => \@sample1Results_2,
    };

$sampleHash{$sample2} = {
    R1Tests  => \@sample2Results_1,
    R2Tests  => \@sample2Results_2,
    };

$sampleHash{$sample3} = {
    R1Tests  => \@sample3Results_1,
    R2Tests  => \@sample3Results_2,
    };
```

I want to print the entire hash into a tab-delimited file that looks like this:

```
sample1  @sample1Results_1[0] @sample1Results_1[1] .... @sample1Results_2[0] @sample1Results_2[1] ...
sample2  @sample2Results_1[0] @sample2Results_1[1] .... @sample2Results_2[0] @sample2Results_2[1] ...
sample3  @sample3Results_1[0] @sample3Results_1[1] .... @sample3Results_2[0] @sample3Results_2[1] ...
```

What is an efficient way to do this? I know it involves a while or foreach loop, but I don't know how to make it print out to a file, do it column wise, and print out both sub-hashes on the same line.

Answer (score 3):

I assume those arrays in your hash are really array *references*, and the semicolons are really commas?

It's very simple really. There are a few ways to do it, but I would use `each` to iterate over the samples, and `join` to assemble the contents.

Like this (*untested*, as I have only a tablet to hand while I'm travelling)

```
while (my ($sample, $results) = each %sampleHash) {
    print join("\t",
            $sample,
            @{ $results->{R1Tests} },
            @{ $results->{R2Tests} }
    ), "\n";
}
```

Comment: One more thing to assume: $sampleHash{$sample1} etc. are really $sampleHash{'sample1'} etc.

Comment: Thanks, @Borodin! And thanks for the heads up with the semi-colons and references. Edited to show the correct syntax.

Comment: When declaring/building the hashes, are the curly braces correct, or should it be parentheses instead?

Comment: @PinkSharpie: If you mean the code in your question, then it is correct as it stands.